# I can't find any servers online, is it just me?

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2

I tried finding some servers after finally installing it today (bought it a year ago during the Summer Sale).

For some reason, when I tried random Matchmaking, I was entered into a completely empty server.  When I went to the server browser, there was no servers listed at all.

I have a perfectly fine internet connection, and I have hit the Reset button multiple times.  Why are no servers showing up for me? I live on the East Coast.

Comment: I would'nt be surprise that EA games had closed those servers in order to low maintenance costs and to force people to buy newest versions of the game. They have done the same on FIFA games recently. You can't play FIFA 10 online anymore. It could be the same for this "old" game that doesn't bring money anymore.

Comment: @TCHdvlp +1. You could probably make that an answer.

Comment: It's just a supposition.

Comment: I have checked the steam community forums, and there are posts from only a few days ago that show they have plenty of 32/32 servers, but for some reason, my server browser shows virtually no servers at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have Battlefield Bad Company 2 [BFBC2] on PC as well.  There are still a lot of servers running for BFBC2 on PC, though I can't speak for consoles.  I wouldn't doubt it if they shut down the official EA servers though.

If you head directly to the Server Browser and select refresh they should pop up.  If they don't I would recommend checking to make sure your Server Filter isn't messed up trying to filter for a Counter Strike map or equivalent (it has happened to me before).

The [Reddit BFBC2 Community](https://www.reddit.com/r/badcompany2/) is still quite active for a game that came out in 2010.  I hope this helps!